# Cannot read Gremlin data from remote after writing

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I use Java to connect to a "remote" (localhost:8182) Gremlin server **g** this way:

```
traversalSource = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using("localhost", 8182, "g"));
```

Then, I write some node like this:

```
traversalSource.addV("TenantProfile");
```

From Gremlin console, connected to the same Gremlin server, I see all created nodes and edges

```
gremlin> g==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:42 edges:64], standard]
```

and queries work, but if I read graph from Java, it results **empty**, so querying e.g. like

```
traversalSource.V()
                        .has("label", TENANT_PROFILE_LABEL)
                        .has("fiscal id", "04228480408")
                        .out(OWNS_LABEL)
                        .has("type", "SH")
                        .values("description")
                        .toList();
```

returns an emtpy list.

Could anyone help me solve this mistery, please?
Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to say I invoke `iterate()` at the end of insertions (triple dots were deleted by editor, I guess)

Comment: I'm not sure that to make of this issue. If you have the same graph data and your traversal works in Gremlin Console against that data then I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't get the same result from Java especially if you terminate your traversal with a terminal step like `toList()`. I think you will have to try to provide a more complete example with some sample data that reproduces this problem.

Comment: one think i'm just noticing is that you included this ">graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:42 edges:64], standard]" as evidence that your data is present. That's demonstrating a local embedded connection to your graph not a remote one, which means that it's possible you're not really proving that Gremlin Console is getting data from Gremlin Server. Again, you may want to edit your question to include a more complete demonstration of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to Stephen, I post the last instructions before `iterate()`

```
for (final Map<String, String> edgePropertyMap : edgePropertyTable) {
            edgeTraversal = traversalSource
                            .V(vertices.get(edgePropertyMap.get(FROM_KEY)))
                            .addE(edgeLabel)
                            .to(vertices.get(edgePropertyMap.get(TO_KEY)));

            final Set<String> edgePropertyNames = edgePropertyMap.keySet();
            for (final String nodePropertyName : edgePropertyNames)
                if ((!nodePropertyName.equals(FROM_KEY)) && (!nodePropertyName.equals(TO_KEY))) {
                    final String edgePropertyValue = edgePropertyMap.get(nodePropertyName);
                    edgeTraversal = edgeTraversal.property(nodePropertyName, edgePropertyValue);
                }

            edgeTraversal.as(edgePropertyMap.get(IDENTIFIER_KEY)).iterate();
        }
```

Anyway, if no `iterate()` were present, how could nodes and edges be visible from inside console? How could they have been "finalized" on remote server?

Comment: you should probably delete this answer and instead edit your question as it now appears as though you have an answer to your inquiry. That said, I don't think this little snippet of code is especially helpful in diagnosing the problem.